# How to change one ActiveRecord model attribute when another attribute changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Consider a simple example: a `User` class with `sms_phone_number` (string) and `sms_number_is_verified` (boolean) model attributes.

An existing user with an already-verified number now changes their phone number:

```rb
user.sms_phone_number = '+14085551212'
user.save!
```

This new number isn’t verified yet, so `sms_number_is_verified` should be set to `false` in the same transaction that updates the phone number.

### Approach 1: Override the Setter

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def sms_phone_number=(val)
    @sms_number_is_verified = false if val != @sms_phone_number
    @sms_phone_number = val
  end
end
```

#### Questions

- What will/won't work if I take this simple approach?

### Approach 2: Dirty + Callbacks

Include [ActiveModel::Dirty](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html), and do something like:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :update_sms_verification

  def update_sms_verification
    if saved_change_to_sms_phone_number?
      sms_number_is_verified = false
    end
  end
end
```

- What will/won't work here?
- Is `before_save` the right callback to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use before_update call back and use field changed?
sms_phone_number_changed? is to check whether field changed from previous value

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  before_update :set_number_not_verified

  def set_number_not_verified
    if sms_phone_number_changed? && sms_phone_number.size > 0
      @sms_number_is_verified = false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: since you do it specific for correction, it's prefer to use before update (the record has already persist, meanwhile before save will run on both new record or updating record, here link active record life cycle for your preference https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#updating-an-object

Comment: It could be a `before_save` callback but a `before_update` is enough, a `before_save` by default is triggered in create and/or update actions unless you specify something else, and in your case `sms_number_is_verified` _must_ have a default value of `false`, so, isn't needed to update anything once the record is created, the `sms_number_is_verified` column is updated only if the condition returns true and that must only happen when updating the row.

Comment: Thanks. One more thing, looks like `sms_phone_number_changed?` is not correct after rails 5.2 and it is replaced by `saved_change_to_sms_phone_number?`. Will this still work in a `before_update` callback?

Comment: yes, since I still using it with rails 6, this still inside rails module version 6.03.1 https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html